# JQuery datepicker plugin: How to set existing date (such as one in the past)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have jquery datepicker working on my form, however I have existing values (typically in the past) for the selected date field.  When I click the field datepicker opens, but shows today's date instead of the existing date.

Ex:

[image]

What do I need to do to pass the existing value to datepicker, so it will go to that date instead of changing to today's date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be out of date for the version of the datepicker you're using, but I think you can also set the default date when you instantiate the datepicker, like so:

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    defaultDate: '01/26/2014'
});
```

So for what you're trying to do (I think) you'd want to pass the textbox value as the default date, in this scenario.

Comment: This is getting me on track.  I need to work with YYYY-MM-DD format.. I think I saw how to do that in the docs.

Comment: [jQuery UI date formatting](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) -- the ISO format I think will do what you need. You can set the `dateFormat` option to "yy-mm-dd".

Comment: This did the trick:  `<script>
      $( function() {
       $("#date_birth").datepicker({
           dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
           defaultDate: '1987-05-01' 
       });
      } );
     </script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setDate` function. For example:

```
$("div").datepicker('setDate', date);​
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is an example how to set the date to something in the past on initializing jQuery's datepicker.

Note that the javascript `Date` object uses a base of 0 for month start. So *0 = January* and *11 = December*.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $datepicker = $('#datepicker');
  $datepicker.datepicker();
  $datepicker.datepicker('setDate', new Date(1997,10,17));  
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```